# Is there an app similar to night mode available for Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone, reading

I am a daily news reader and use MSN news for that purpose but the app lacks an inbuilt night mode option. It is difficult to read the MSN news app at night without a night mode option.

Can you tell me whether a night mode app similar to [Night mode (Android)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pt.bbarao.nightmode&hl=en) is available in Windows Phone 8.1?

Comment: Can you check some kind of browser ( UC , Opera ) might have this feature so you can possibly visit msn news from that browser and use night mode.

Comment: I want to read news from MSN news apps (available in app store) not from the websites. And UC's nighmode work only with that app. i was looking for a "universal" night mode for wp8.1

Comment: As I am not a Windows Phone user (hence, a comment instead of an answer), I cannot verify whether the apps do exactly what you want but check out [Night Mode Browser](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/night-mode-browser/9nblggh081qs#ratings-reviews) and [Night Browser](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/night-browser/9nblggh0fhrs#system-requirements), maybe they can fit you.